# iMacros extract information from div into variable

Tags: html, variables, extract, imacros

I am trying to create a function which extracts a piece of information in a div then saves it to a variable.The variable is then put into a sentence like "Hi my name is " xthen sends the messageI need help writing the function and putting it into the sentence at the moment it looks like this

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Send<SP>a<SP>message
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:sendMessage ATTR=ID:mySubject CONTENT=Hello
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:sendMessage ATTR=ID:myMessage CONTENT=Hello<SP>my<SP>name<SP>is
```

I want to extract Jack from this

```
<div id="main">
<div class="container">
<div id="content">
<div id="box">
<div id="boxMain">
<div id="contentHeader" class="profileHeader">
<h1>Jack</h1>
<div class="right hidden"><span id="divsk"></span></div>
<div class="break"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no Jack in stated html

Answer (score 1):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

For the rest use JS scripting. :)